# IJavaScript not working/linking properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently started learning HTML,CSS and Javascript and i am still getting the hang of it.

I want the hidden menu to be shown (menu) when the div class (mainLeft) is clicked. but, my javascript query to hide/show it doesn't work.

**HTML Code**

```
<head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="satmap.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\mbashir\Documents\HTML\satmap.js"></script>

<title>SATMAP Home</title>
</head>

 <body>

    <div id="main">
    <h1> XYZ</h1>
    </div>

  <div id="mainLeft">
    <h1> Current Stats </h1>
  </div>

  <div id="SME">
    <h4> my Explorer </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="DataAnalysis">
    <h4> Data Analysis </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="ProdMonitor">
    <h4> Production Monitoring </h4>
  </div>

    <div class="menu">

  <div class="icon-close">
    <h4> Disappear </h4>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Gain Table</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Remember Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

**CSS Code**

```
 body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1{
font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Candara; 
}

h4{
font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: Candara; 
}

#main {
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #13b5ea;
}
#SME {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  background-color:#13b5ea;
}

#DataAnalysis {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 38.3%;
  top: 28%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-color:#13b5ea;
}

#ProdMonitor {
  display: table;
  background-color:#13b5ea;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 38.3%;
  top: 72%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
   }

#mainLeft {
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #13b5ea;
  cursor: pointer;
}

    .menu {
  background-color:#13b5ea;
  left: -285px;  
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}
  .menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var main = function(){
  $('#mainLeft').click(function(){
      $('.menu').animate({
          left:'0px'
     },200);

    $('body').animate({
      left: '285px'
    }, 200);
   });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: `C:\Users\mbashir\Documents\HTML\satmap.js` is probably your problem.

Comment: You aren't loading JQuery

Comment: i have tried simple **satmap.jss** too, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: to expand on zzzzBov's answer, you should make that link relative to your html page. It will look something like just '/satmap.js'

Comment: Ook. How do i do that. Sorry for silly questions but I am still in my learning and googling phase and I have googled it a lot. I tried "linking the js" etc.

Comment: Forget `satmap.js`. You aren't loading the JQuery library so your code will not work

Comment: Ok. And I hope you don't mind me asking you "How do i do that". I mean I have tried googling but I am not sure if I understand it. I have bootstrap on my laptop but I wanted to try everything on my own before jumping onto third party files

Comment: You can load it from the JQuery CDN by adding the following to your page _before_ your javascript code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Bootstrap and Jquery are completely separate things. The javascript in your question is actually JQuery, a Javascript library, and so requires the JQuery library to be loaded before you can run your code

Comment: Thank you every one. I got it. The click finally worked. Although the body didn't move, just the menu showed up, but i will fix that on my own. But Thank you guys a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that your javascript is firing at all? Such as adding `console.log('test')` or `alert('test')`? If it is firing, then you can move on to look at other things.

I think your problem might be because you're animating a `left` value that doesn't mean anything yet because the elements haven't been given a CSS `position` value that uses it. Try giving the `#mainLeft` element a `position: absolute` and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried both the things but none of them worked. I am trying to google it too and ask my seniors (who are asleep). I need to get it right tonight otherwise I wont sleep before I get the code right :)

Comment: Ok, if the `alert('test')` didn't work, that means your javascript isn't linked right. I would examine the file path to your javascript file and make sure it's correct (and possibly use a relative path if they are in the same folder).

Comment: Yes, that is what i thought that it must not be linked properly. I googled a lot about linking the js correctly and making sure the path is correct but I couldnt get it right. They are in the same folder so how do i **properly link them**

Comment: If they are in the same folder, your entire path should just be `<script src="satmap.js"></script>`

Comment: Ah ... just saw that a commenter noticed you aren't loading jQuery, but your code is written with jQuery. You need to load a version of the jQuery library before your satmap.js file for it to work.

Comment: I tried that too earlier and now again. But that doesn't work either :( 
I am sorry I am taking too much of your time. Someone else said that my jquery library isnt loaded and that might be problem?

Comment: Yes, and how do I load it?

Comment: It's a javascript file just like your satmap.js file. You can download it from jquery.com and link it, or you can add this code to link to a google-hosted version: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have said the JS file is in the same folder as the page, so you would link it like:

```
<script src="satmap.js"></script>
```

Also noted, is in the HTML provided, you did not have JQuery Library included, and since the coding you were using is dependent on JQuery, that would be a problem! :)
You can download the JQuery library from [JQuery.com](http://jquery.com/), or link to the CDN host like:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```